# How to sum numbers from a table with mySQL

Tags: mysql

I'm using phpMyAdmin and I have two tables:

**___SalesTaxes**

```
|--------|----------|------------|
| STX_Id | STX_Name | STX_Amount |
|--------|----------|------------|
|      1 |    Tax 1 |       5.00 |
|      2 |    Tax 2 |      13.50 |
|--------|----------|------------|
```

**___BillableDatas**

```
|--------|---------------|------------|------------|----------|---------------------|
| BIL_Id | BIL_BookingId | BIL_Date   | BIL_Status | BIL_Rate | BIL_ApplicableTaxes |
|--------|---------------|------------|------------|----------|---------------------|
|      1 |             2 | 2018-03-06 | notcharged |   100.00 |                   1 |
|      2 |             2 | 2018-03-07 | notcharged |   105.00 |                 1,2 |
|--------|---------------|------------|------------|----------|---------------------|
```

---

I want to list per day a list of the billable things in `___BillableDatas` depending the status of the thing (charged vs notcharged).

So something like this:

```
|------------|-----------------|--------------------|------------------|--------------------|
|    Date    | BIL_Sum_Charged | BIL_Sum_Notcharged | Taxes_ForCharged | TaxesForNotCharged |
|------------|-----------------|--------------------|------------------|--------------------|
| 2018-03-06 |            0.00 |             100.00 |             0.00 |               5.00 |
| 2018-03-07 |            0.00 |             105.00 |             0.00 |              19.42 |
|------------|-----------------|--------------------|------------------|--------------------|
```

---

Note that the following query returns the previous table (the first 3 columns only):

```
SELECT BIL_Date, 
ifnull(sum(case when BIL_Status = "charged" then BIL_Rate else 0 end), 0) 
as BIL_Sum_Charged, 
ifnull(sum(case when BIL_Status = "notcharged" then BIL_Rate else 0 end), 0) 
as BIL_Sum_Notcharged 
FROM ___BillableDatas 
WHERE BIL_HotelId='cus_CNHLMiMOzP5cuM' 
AND BIL_BookingId='2' 
GROUP BY BIL_Date 
ORDER BY BIL_Date 
ASC
```

---

How can I generate the two other columns ?

Please see the SQL Fiddle:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e1208e/2

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: You appear to have comma separated values

Comment: Hello @Strawberry, yes I know it's not the best structure I have. I have on my plans to change this but actually i'm stuck with that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use FIND_IN_SET to join the Tax and Billable tables, then sum the tax amount:

```
SELECT b.BIL_Date, 
ifnull(sum(case when b.BIL_Status = "charged" then b.BIL_Rate else 0 end), 0) 
as BIL_Sum_Charged, 
ifnull(sum(case when b.BIL_Status = "notcharged" then b.BIL_Rate else 0 end), 0) 
as BIL_Sum_Notcharged,
ifnull(sum(case when b.BIL_status = "charged" then s.STX_Amount else 0 end), 0) 
as STX_TAX_Charged,
ifnull(sum(case when b.BIL_status = "notcharged" then s.STX_Amount else 0 end), 0) 
as STX_TAX_NotCharged
FROM ___BillableDatas b
INNER JOIN ___SalesTaxes s
ON FIND_IN_SET(s.STX_id, b.BIL_ApplicableTaxes) > 0
WHERE b.BIL_HotelId='cus_CNHLMiMOzP5cuM' 
AND b.BIL_BookingId='2' 
GROUP BY b.BIL_Date 
ORDER BY b.BIL_Date 
ASC
```

Comment: Hello and first, thanks to help me with this. Do you know with your solution `BIL_Sum_Notcharged` for 2018-03-07 is not equal to 210.00 whereas it should be 105.00 ?

Comment: Another thing is to calculate automatically in `BIL_Sum_Notcharged` and `STX_TAX_NotCharged` the taxes amount and not the taxes sum. Thanks.